# Performance of Android using HttpClient with Apache server running php scripts with Memcache

Tags: java, php, android, apache

I have an application in which an Android device is connected to a data acquisition system and the data is stored in a local db.  I want to monitor in real time the data on a second Android as well.  In order to enhance performance, I set up my own Apache server (XAMPP) on a Windows machine.  I wrote two php scripts; one to store data in Memcache and one to get data from memcache.  The Android devices are using HttpClient to call the scripts.  I used memcache in order to eliminate some delays of writing to database.  Below is the code used for sending and receiving the data...  For testing, it is a simple loop (counter) with a thread delay.  If I set the delay for 1 second, the textview is updated and runs smoothly.  When I drop the delay to 0.1 seconds, it runs fine for a few seconds and then stutters (pauses) for 3-5 seconds.  It continues this process of intermittent pausing while running.  If I drop the delay to 0.01 seconds, the system crashes.  My Apache server is connected to directly to my router.  The Android devices are connected to my WiFi.  My question is whether or not I'm doing something fundamentally wrong.  I thought with memcache, I would easily be able to do 0.01 s sampling of data.  Is my code properly handling the AsyncTasks?  How can I prevent the Android system from apparently becoming "overloaded" with new tasks?  It is as if I need a method to determine when a task is complete such that the next task can be called.  I appreciate any feedback regarding php, httpclient, etc...anything that affects performance.

EDIT:  My system no longer crashes when I drop the delay to 0.01 sec.  I now have a catch for the null value in the onpostexecute method.  However, I still get stutters/freezes.

```
    private void startsendingdata() {
            loop = 0;
            if (sendingdatathread != null)
                sendingdatathread.interrupt();
            sendingdatathread = new Thread() {
                public void run() {
                    while (loop < 5000) {
                        try {
                            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                                @Ov

erride
                            public void run() {
                                new SendDataTask().execute();
                                loop++;
                                myvar = Integer.toString(loop);
                            }
                        });
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

        };
        sendingdatathread.start();

    }

    private class SendDataTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Double> {

        @Override
        protected Double doInBackground(String... params) {
            postData();
            return null;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Double result) {
        }

        public void postData() {
            try {
                List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                // put all variables here (with connection code attached)
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("connectioncode",
                        connectioncode));

                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("myvar", myvar));

                httppostsend
                        .setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                response = httpclient.execute(httppostsend);
                response.getEntity().consumeContent();

            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

    }

    private void startgettingdata() {

        if (gettingdatathread != null)
            gettingdatathread.interrupt();
        gettingdatathread = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                while (true) {
                    try {
                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                new GetDataTask().execute();
                            }
                        });
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

        };
        gettingdatathread.start();
    }

    private class GetDataTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Double> {

        @Override
        protected Double doInBackground(String... params) {

            getData();

            return null;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Double result) {
            if (!line.isEmpty() && line!=null&&connectioncode.length() >= 6) {


                tvLapTime.setText("MyVar: " + myvar);
            }

        }

        public void getData() {
            if (connectioncode.length() >= 6) {
                try {
                    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("connectioncode",
                            connectioncode));
                    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

                    response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                    entity = response.getEntity();
                    is = entity.getContent();
                    line = convertInputStreamToString(is);
                    response.getEntity().consumeContent();
                } catch (ClientProtocolException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // convert inputstream to String
        private static String convertInputStreamToString(InputStream inputStream)
                throws IOException {
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
            String result = "";
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
                result += line;
        try {
            json = new JSONObject(result);
        } catch (JSONException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        if (json != null) {
            try {

                myvar = json.getString(connectioncode + "myvar");
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        inputStream.close();
        return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Do away with startsendingdata() and startgettingdata(). In the onPostExecute() of the tasks initiate the start of the next task. Now you are sure a task is finished before starting a new one. For instance you could start a timer which executes the next task.

Comment: The only reason I can't put the next task in the onPostExecute is because there are two separate Android devices.  One device is doing the sending from Activity A.  The other Android device is getting the data from Activity B.  For the sample code I put above, it would work, but not for my app.  Is there another way of syncing up the sends and gets on two separate devices?

Comment: You did not mention before that sends and gets should be in sync. And my solution does not pretend that.